# Lookup of entries with multiplicities

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `data <- c(1,2,2,1)` and a reference table, say : `ref <- cbind(c(1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4), c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))`

I would like my code to return the following vector : `result <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,1,2)`. It's like using the R function `match()`. But `match()` only returns the first occurrence of the reference vector. Similar for `%in%`.

I have tried functions like `merge()`, `join()` but I would like something with only the combination of `rep()` and `seq()` R functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
ref[ref[,1] %in% data,2]
```

To return the second column value whenever the first column value is in the given set.  You can wrap this in a lapply:

```
unlist(lapply(data, function(x) ref[ref[,1] ==x, 2]))
```

Comment: Actually, looking at the result, you probably want `unlist(lapply(data, function(x) ref[ref[,1] ==x, 2]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices you are looking for like this:

```
indices <- sapply(data,function(xx)which(ref[,1]==xx))
```

Of course, that is a `list`, since the number of hits will be different for each entry of `data`. So you just `unlist()` this:

```
ref[unlist(indices),2]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 1 2
```